# Object detection in bitmap JavaScript canvas

Tags: algorithm, javascript, data-structure

I want to detect clicks on canvas elements which are drawn using paths. So far I have stored element paths in a JavaScript data structure and then check the coordinates of hits which match the element's coordinates. Rendering each element path and checking the hits would be inefficient when there are a lot of elements. I believe there must be an algorithm for this kind of coordinate search, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can probably also try using pixel color for detection. As far i know EaselJS it in the algorithms

Comment: If you can name any algorithm particulary for this purpose or steps instead of library it would be nice.

Comment: I am not sure about the steps. But something like this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735470/get-pixel-color-from-canvas-on-mouseover
can be used in the algorithm

Answer (score 2):

You should probably take a look at engines that already do that like:

- [CAAT](http://labs.hyperandroid.com/static/caat/)
- [EaselJS](http://createjs.com/#!/EaselJS)

But I'm pretty sure they maintain some state relative to position and shape and check against those for every frame update.